# Where does an execution plan come from?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan, cache

Is there a way I can determine if a plan was just generated for a particular query, or was found in the plan cache?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQL Server 2012 has an indicator in the plan itself, `RetrievedFromCache`, which can be either "true" or "false".

This appears to be the property you are asking about.

This is a sample (the last line shows the property):

```
<StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" 
StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" 
StatementSubTreeCost="0.0508992" StatementText="SELECT COUNT(*) 
&#xD;&#xA;FROM sys.tables" StatementType="SELECT" 
QueryHash="0x9A4B63A948B30EA0" QueryPlanHash="0xF357CAE882D5B15D" 
RetrievedFromCache="true">
```

Unfortunately, I do not see anything similar in a plan generated by SQL Server 2008 R2.

In SQL Server 2008 R2, you can use the `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` system DMV to inspect the `creation_time` column for plans that have the same `query_hash` value.  The query hash can be obtained from the header of the plan XML (see the example above).  This query will return rows regarding the plan mentioned above:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
WHERE qs.query_hash = 0x9A4B63A948B30EA0;
```